# How to build/package wso2 api manager Identity Server as Key Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I can build wso2 api management from https://github.com/wso2/product-apim. But how could i build Identity Server as Key Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the instructions for building the IS as KM pack in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v2.6.0/modules/is-km